# How do I calculate the area around a given point

Tags: c#, .net, geometry, 2d

Let's say I have the coordinates 0, 0 as my center point. And I want to calculate an area that extrudes 6 tiles (1 tile being 1 unit) each direction from the center point, essentially building a rectangle that's 13x13 based on the center point.

This is what I have, but I feel  as if that's not correct.

```
class Program
{
    static Point AbsPos = new Point(0, 0);
    static Point Rectangle;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Rectangle = new Point(AbsPos.X * 13, AbsPos.Y * 13);
    }
}
```

Comment: If coordinates mattered to you and you are not just after the area of a square :/, just for reference  `var rectangle = new Rectangle(absPos, Size.Empty);` and `rectangle.Inflate((size - 1) / 2, (size - 1) / 2);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a grid of same-shaped tiles, the location of the center of a square has no influence on its area. A 13x13 square has an area of 169 regardless of whether it's located at 0,0 or 17,22. If your user is going to give you `6` as an input then you simply need to do:

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Pow((2 * input) + 1, 2));
```

Comment: Ah! I see! Thank you so much! I'll accept this answer as soon as it let's me